# Can I change the format of a Zedgraph axis without redrawing each curve?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Basically, my application has a zedgraph plot, with a curve already loaded.

Intrinsically (i.e. in a database where the curve points are stored as x-y pairs), each point's x-value is a double which represents the time (in seconds) that has elapsed for that particular point from a variable DateTime initialTime, which could be something like 'December 15, 2005 12:45:02pm'.

I give my user the option of displaying the x-axis as 'relative time' (time elapsed since initialTime which are simply the original values)  or 'actual time' (full date/time of each point). Currently, every time the user switches time views, I have to iterate through each PointPair on the PointPairList of the curve and translate the x-values to/from original values and the Zedgraphs XDate format.

Is there another way to do it more efficiently? I was thinking about only changing zgc.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Format in a way such that it accounts for this translation, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking about only changing zgc.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Format

Could you just change the axis labels under `zgc.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.TextLabels` (which is an array of strings)?

Comment: Sorry for responding rather late. My application is constantly adding points to the graph, so adding text labels becomes inefficient after a while since the TextLabels property is a string array. If only it were a list...

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just update the axis like so?

```
zedgraph.AxisChange(); 

this.Refresh();
```